# Module isomorphic to second dual

Tags: modules

Is there a simple condition on a module $M$ over a ring $R$ which will ensure that $M$ is isomorphic to its double dual, $M^{**} = \operatorname{Hom} (\operatorname{Hom}(M,R),R)$? What about a condition on $R$ which guarantees this will hold for all $R$-modues $M$? Can we find conditions which are necessary, as well as sufficient?

Comment: If $M$ is a finitely-generated _free_ $R$-module, then there is such an isomorphism. I suspect the only ring for which double-dualisation is an isomorphism is the trivial ring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is true if $M$ is finitely-generated projective (see for example [these notes](http://www.math.unipd.it/~frank/ALGANT/2005/chap4b.pdf)). I'm not aware of a more general condition that's reasonably easy to state.

I agree with Zhen that probably no nontrivial ring has this property for *all* $M$. This is not even true for fields (if $M$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space then the natural map to the double dual is never an isomorphism).

Comment: I should mention that that last fact is contingent on the axiom of choice. It may actually be consistent with ZF that this is not true...

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 14):

A module which is isomorphic to its double dual under the natural map is called *reflexive*. These are objects that have been rather carefully studied in commutative algebra.

As noted in the other answers/comments, a finitely generated projective module over a ring $R$ is necessarily reflexive.  Conversely if $R$ is a regular local commutative ring of dimension $\leq 2$, then any f.g. reflexive module is projective (equivalently, free, since we are over a local ring).  This is not true if the dimension is $> 2$; in that case there are f.g. reflexive modules that are not free.

[This MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7490/differences-between-reflexives-and-projectives-modules/7588#7588) provides more information, including a characterization of f.g. reflexive modules over an integrally closed domain in terms of other standard module theoretic properties.